# Error when try to delete row in access database

Tags: c#, ms-access

Hello guys i`m trying to delete a row in a access database but when i try to update the dataset it give me this error

```
Update requires a valid DeleteCommand when passed DataRow collection with deleted rows.
```

I tryed to solve it on my own but i cant seem to fix it. So if anyone can give me an advice i will be very thankful. Here is my code.

```
            currentRow = e.RowIndex;
            ds1 = new DataSet();
            con = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=DataSource/PhoneBookData.mdb";
            con.Open();
            string sql = "SELECT * From CONTACT";
            da = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con);
            da.Fill(ds1, "CONTACT");

            DataRow dRow = ds1.Tables["CONTACT"].Rows[0];
            ds1.Tables["CONTACT"].Rows[currentRow].Delete();
            da.Update(ds1, "CONTACT");
```

Thanks for all the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is exact on what your problem is - you are missing the DeleteCommand in the adapter:

```
da = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbAdapter( ... );
da.DeleteCommand = "DELETE ....";
```